# Drag And Drop Vanilla JS with a generated div

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

Can someone explain to me how you can make a div dragable when the div itself is  created only after you clicked on a button  that will add the div like a to do list ?  i

Comment: Do you know of a website that has the feature you're describing? If so, provide a link to help illustrate what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: the Trello Website

Answer (score 1):

MDN has good documentation on how this works in vanilla js.  You could start with something like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API.

It's unclear exactly what you're asking, though.  How exactly do you want this div to appear - rendered somewhere on the page after clicking the button, then later dragged, or immediately in a dragging state, or something else?

The drag/drop API will support both of what I described above, but getting each to work requires different approaches.  Clarification here would help.